# How to differentiate a ceramic pan from a teflon one?

Tags: equipment, frying-pan, ceramic, teflon

I was in the store looking to buy a new pan, i found in the local store they sell them but i can't tell if this is a real ceramic or just white teflon (i don't know if that exist) both pans had similar surface/texture to the touch, so that made me doubt of that.

How i can tell the difference between ceramic and teflon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have never seen white teflon coating on cookware (even if white teflon exists in other applications); if you want to minimize exposure to teflon fumes in case of overheating accidents (eg if you have pet birds in the house), be aware that some ceramic lined pans have a teflon protected *outside*.

Some black/grey/patterned "ceramic" coatings, however, seem to be hybrid (teflon reinforced with ceramic dust).

If in doubt, check whether there is a manufacturer and product name for the coating mentioned on the packaging - this is common with good quality coated cookware, you can then look up the specs for it on the internet. If such research yields unclear results, that does not speak for the quality of the coating.

Be aware that the average ceramic coating you'll find on cookware is far from equal to teflon in nonstick properties, seems to be *more* sensitive to thermal shock or other damage - while it will not come off, it will quickly lose the nonstick properties. Also, white ceramic coatings can stain.